# Hadoop Mapreduce Functionality

Tags: hadoop, hive

Suppose I want to perform **Select** query with **"Order By"** Clause, and my data is distributed over **multiple machine**. How *Map reduce Fetch data* and where it perform **"Order By"** Query.

Answer (score 0):

Map-Reduce can be used to implement a distributed "Order By".

> ... One of Yahoo’s Hadoop clusters sorted 1 terabyte of data in 209
> seconds ... The sort used 1800 maps and 1800 reduces ...
>
> [Apache Hadoop Wins Terabyte Sort Benchmark](http://yahoohadoop.tumblr.com/post/98115409811/apache-hadoop-wins-terabyte-sort-benchmark)

This can be done by mapping the order keys to ranges, by their values.

---

Hive however, is implementing "Order By" with a single reducer.

> ... in order to impose total order of all results, there has to be one
> reducer to sort the final output. If the number of rows in the output
> is too large, the single reducer could take a very long time to
> finish...
>
> [Hive - LanguageManual - Sort By - Syntax of Order By](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofOrderBy)

Comment: How it Decides, how many map & reduce task will be required for query execution? And Where Reducer Sort the Final Output(In which Memory)?

Comment: Maps based on the data source size (but some data formats are limited to 1 map). reducers - 1

Comment: And Where Reducer Sort the Final Output(In which Memory)?

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: As You said:

"in order to impose total order of all results, there has to be one reducer to sort the final output"

So my Question is where this one reducer Sort the final output? In Which Data Node final "Order By" is perform?  

Or Is it like after performing "ORDER BY" in each node and the total output(1TB data) is Gathered in Master node and there it perform the final "ORDER BY" clause?

Comment: Why does it matter? In any case it suffers from the same limitation.